# How to manage Textblock embedded in Button in XAML?

Tags: c#, button, win-universal-app, textblock, launcher

I develop an Universal App where there are some views based on a **"Contact's page" presentation** to show details from contacts or companies.

For each item, I display the **"label"** in a first **TextBlock** and the **"data"** in another **TextBlock**.

For example, this page shows details of a company:

[image: First Screenshot]

The XAML is very simple:

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <!-- 1. Company name -->
            <TextBlock Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Text="Company"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.name}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
            <!-- 2. Phone -->
            <TextBlock Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Text="Phone" 
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.phone}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" 
                       FontWeight="Normal" />
            <!-- 3. Fax -->
            <TextBlock x:Uid="commonTextblockFax"
                       Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Text="Fax" 
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.fax}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
            <!-- 4. Location -->
            <TextBlock Text="Location"
                       Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.address_line_1}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" 
                       FontWeight="Normal" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.address_line_2}"  
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" 
                       FontWeight="Normal" />
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"
                       FontWeight="Normal" >
                <Run Text="{Binding Company.postal}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Company.city}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <!-- 5. Website-->
            <TextBlock Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Text="Website" 
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.website}"  
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" 
                       FontWeight="Normal" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

But some of these informations must be **binding to a launcher**:

- **phone number** : shows a MenuFlyout that offers choice between call or sms
- **email** : launches the email app
- **location** : launches the maps app

So, I tried to **put the "data" Textblock into a Button**, in order to call each launcher through **Command**

This is the new XAML:

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <!-- 1. Company -->
            <TextBlock Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Text="Company"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.name}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />

            <!-- 2. Phone -->
            <TextBlock Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Text="Phone" 
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <Button Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
                <Button.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Call" 
                            Tag="call"
                            Command="{Binding PhoneCallCommand}"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Send SMS" 
                            Tag="SMS" 
                            Command="{Binding PhoneSmsCommand}"/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </Button.Flyout>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.phone}" 
                           Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" 
                           FontWeight="Normal" />
            </Button>

            <!-- 3. Fax -->
            <TextBlock x:Uid="commonTextblockFax"
                       Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Text="Fax" 
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.fax}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />

            <!-- 4. Location -->
            <TextBlock Text="Location"
                       Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <Button Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    Command="{Binding MapCommand}" >
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.address_line_1}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" 
                               FontWeight="Normal" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.address_line_2}"  
                               Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" 
                               FontWeight="Normal" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"
                               FontWeight="Normal" >
                        <Run Text="{Binding Company.postal}"/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Company.city}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>

            <!-- 5. Website -->
            <TextBlock Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Text="Website" 
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}" />
            <Button Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    Command="{Binding LinkCommand}" >
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.website}"  
                           Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" 
                           FontWeight="Normal" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

=> The launchers works fine:

[image]

But there is now a **"gap"** between my items, as we can see between the "Phone number" and the "fax" label:

[image]

I tried to fix it, by adding a **negative margin ("0,0,0,-10") to the Button**:

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <!-- 1. Company -->
            <TextBlock Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Text="Company"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.name}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />

            <!-- 2. Phone -->
            <TextBlock Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Text="Phone" 
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <Button Margin="0,0,0,-10">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
                <Button.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Call" 
                            Tag="call"
                            Command="{Binding PhoneCallCommand}"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Send SMS" 
                            Tag="SMS" 
                            Command="{Binding PhoneSmsCommand}"/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </Button.Flyout>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.phone}" 
                           Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" 
                           FontWeight="Normal" />
            </Button>

            <!-- 3. Fax -->
            <TextBlock x:Uid="commonTextblockFax"
                       Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Text="Fax" 
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.fax}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />

            <!-- 4. Location -->
            <TextBlock Text="Location"
                       Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}"/>
            <Button Margin="0,0,0,-10"
                    Command="{Binding MapCommand}" >
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.address_line_1}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" 
                               FontWeight="Normal" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.address_line_2}"  
                               Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" 
                               FontWeight="Normal" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"
                               FontWeight="Normal" >
                        <Run Text="{Binding Company.postal}"/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Company.city}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>

            <!-- 5. Website -->
            <TextBlock Margin="0,9,0,0"
                       Text="Website" 
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeBrush}"
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}" />
            <Button Margin="0,0,0,-10"
                    Command="{Binding LinkCommand}" >
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.website}"  
                           Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" 
                           FontWeight="Normal" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

But there is always a gap in comparison to the first version without the button:
[image]

***=> Is there so a way to do this properly?***

Comment: Very comprehensive and well written question!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a button instead of just the `Tapped` event of the TextBlock?

Comment: Not really a reason, but I don't know if it is possible to shown a MenuFlyout from this event?
Moreover, I wanted to also handle cases where datas are decomposed in many Textblocks, like from "Location" (address-line1, address-line2, postal, city) without having to duplicate the binding to the command.

Comment: Nobody would have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can custom the style of Button, and define your own ContentTemplate.

That way you have complete control over the content of it.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx) is the default style for button to start with.